# Environment variables with wildfly not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, environment-variables, wildfly, application.properties

In my application launching I get some variables from env variables in app properties.

It works fine with spring boot container.

But when I launch the application with wildfly 10 `System.getenv` always return null. I set my env variables in run configuration in STS, also it doesn't work in openshift that run wildfly.

Here is sample of my code:

```
String showSql = System.getenv("SHOW_SQL");

if(value.contains(":")){
    int split = value.indexOf(":");
    List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
    s.add(value.substring(1, split)) ;
    s.add(value.substring(split+1, value.length()-1));
    // value.split(":");

    if(System.getenv(s.get(0)) != null){
        var = System.getenv(s.get(0));
    }else{
        var = s.get(1);
        var = var.replace(":", "");
    }                           
}else{
    value = value.replace("{", "");
    value = value.replaceAll("}", "");
    var = System.getenv(value);
}
```

Can any one help me?

Comment: I suspect the problem is in how you provide the environment variables to the JVM process running wildfly -- perhaps you can think about the difference between that and how you run Spring Boot?

Comment: That isn't a environment variable but a regular java system property. Those are different things. Instead use `System.getProperty`.

Comment: i used it , but it's not working also

Answer (score 0):

You can set a property in Wildfly with the jboss-cli using the command 
/system-property=foo:add(value=bar) which you can get then from your application using System.getProperty (a reload in the meanwhile might be required). The property will be stored into the Wildfly configuration thus it will survive a reboot :)